# Web page in PhoneGap project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, webview

**Hello** *everybody* !

I have a **Phonegap** projet with the **Ionic** *Framework* and **AngularJS**.
**I want to show a web page in my app but keep the navigation bar too.**
The nav bar is a **Ionic** *component* `ion-nav-view`.

**Here is my code** :

```
<ion-view title="Web page">
  <ion-content class="has-header">
      <!-- suppose to show the web page here -->
  </ion-content>   
</ion-view>
```

I tried to use `<iframe>` but I'm not able to scroll on the web page, tried to use `<object>`, same problem.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: normally you should use inappbrowser plugin to open the external webpage, I dont think you can achieve what you want.

Comment: can you make a JSfiddle with your iframe code. I believe scroll should work over iframe. apply style overflow-y:auto; in iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Think this is an issue with whitespace between css blocks. I removed the whitespace between the tags it worked.